# install xfce from a flash drive?

Tags: flash, usb-drive, xfce, software-installation

I was running xubuntu but accidently deleted xfce files. Now xubuntu won't start (I have NO GUI!). Is it possible to download xubuntu to a flash drive and copy it over to my machine? If so what command would I use, from the terminal, to run the flash drive program?

Comment: "deleted xfce files" What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

There is possibly an easier way to do this without building from source or running a deb from a USB. Try connecting your computer via a LAN ethernet cable and try the following: (if you are simply missing dependencies that xfce used to utilise then the following two commands should work to fix application dependencies)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
```

To install xfce4 desktop from scratch then try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Comment: I can't connect to the internet from the linux computer. But I did download an iso of ubuntu to a flash drive. Do I need to use a program to boot from there or can I get terminal to recognize the iso and run it through an installed app? My gui is broken but other programs should run?

Comment: If not is it possible to run UNetbootin from the terminal, to install the iso boot or do I need a gui for it to work?